# Possible arrangments Letters?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements are possible of the letters in **EZPZ I CAN DO IT**, which has five vowels (A, E, I, I, O) and seven consonants (C, D, N, P, T, Z, Z).

a)  if there are no restrictions,

b)  if the letters must be in alphabetical order?

c)  if the vowels must be together?

d)  **6 letter words** if the vowels must be together.

Comment: I edited your tags. More tags does not mean more help.

Comment: first time users. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please share your thoughts on the problem so far. Knowing what you know will help us provide the most useful hints and solutions!

Answer (score 1):

(a) If there are no restrictions, we permute. However, since $I$ and $Z$ are repeated twice, we have to divide out according to the multinomial distribution:

$$\dfrac{12!}{2! * 2!}$$

(b) If you count the two $I$ and two $Z$ characters as the same, there is only one string with the letters in alphabetical order. If you count the two $I$ and two $Z$ characters as distinct, we can swap them, so we get $4$ ways. I would personally treat the $I$ and $Z$ characters as the same.

(c) Start by grouping the vowels. There are $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$ ways to permute the vowels. We then permute the consonants. There are $\dfrac{7!}{2!}$ ways to do this. You then place the vowel cluster in the consonants string. There are $8$ ways to do this. So by rule of product, we get:
$$\dfrac{5! * 7!}{2! * 2!} * 8 $$

(d) We again permute the vowels, which gives us $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$. We then choose a consonant. The $z$ is counted twice, so we have $6$ ways to choose a consonant. It must go at the beginning or end. There are two ways to do this. So by rule of product we get:

$$ \dfrac{5!}{2!} * 6 * 2 = 6! $$

Comment: Note that for (d), I am only describing a single six letter word. If you want two six letter words, I will be happy to update my answer.